# Unable to move a file once I have read and appended data to a new file c#

Tags: c#, foreach

I have a foreach loop that is appending data from 1 file (source) to another (destination).
Once the file has been appended with all data I want to move the original source file. When debugging im getting the error "Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.IO.FileSystem.dll"

Im assuming this is because the file is locked. How can I dispose this so I can move the file.

```
var stringwrite = new[] { prefix, prefix2 };

                        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(currentFile))
                        {
                            var lastOne = line.Split(';').Last();
                            if (!stringwrite.Any(stringwrite => lastOne.Contains(stringwrite)))
                                continue;

                            //write lines found to new file 
                            File.AppendAllText(todestination, line + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        //move original file to new directory 
                        try
                        {
                            File.Move(currentFile, completeddestination);
                            break;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Issue Moving File");
                        }
```

Comment: Mostly likely it is already closed as `ReadLines()` closes file automatically, so there must be another reason, check if you have permissions to move the file. Maybe it is 'readonly' or the app has to be running with elevated permissions or sth

Comment: Checked all permissions and they are correct. Throwing me as like you say ReadLines() closes the file automatically.

Comment: @PeterSmith what 'close file call' do you mean?

Comment: @cragjungle what are the details of the exception? The type alone doesn't say much...

Comment: Specifically "The file already exists". Ive checked it doesn't

Comment: Well, if it says the file already exists, than it is indeed there. What values do you assign to currentFile and completeddestination? That is the most important question here.

Comment: If the exception says, the file already exists, it most certainly does exist. Are you sure, you are using the correct path? Do you use absolute or relative paths? If relative, what is your working directory.

Comment: @PeterSmith How would you close a file, if you don't have any handle to that file?

Comment: You can also use `Path.GetFullPath(completeddestination)` to get the absolute path of your file and then check under this absolute path

Answer (score 0):

As you are reading the source file to the end and writing to the destination depending on a condition, it would make sense to keep both input and output streams open until the end of read/write operations. Note, that `File.ReadLines` will open the source file, read the contents, and then close it. Also, `File.AppendAllText` will open the destination file, append the contents, and then close the file. Such an approach is inefficient. I think, your task could be properly implemented using file streams. Please find the example below:

```
static void Main()
{
    var sourcePath = "C:\\PathToSource";
    var destinationPath = "C:\\PathToDestination";
    var completedDestinationPath = "C:\\PathToCompletedDestination";
    
    var prefixes = new[] { "some-prefix", "some-other-prefix" };
    
    foreach (var source in EnumerateDataFiles(sourcePath))
    {
        // This assumes that files in source and destination and completed
        // dectination directories have the same file name but different paths.
        // If you use another convention for your data, please adjust it here
        var destination = GetDestinationFilePath(source, destinationPath);
        var completedDestination = GetDestinationFilePath(source, completedDestinationPath);
        
        try
        {
            AppendData(
                source,
                destination,
                line =>
                {
                    var lastEntry = line.Split(';').Last();
                    return prefixes.Any(prefix => lastEntry.Contains(prefix));
                });
        
            File.Move(source, completedDestination);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Issue Moving File: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateDataFiles(string path)
{
    // Change *.dat to the extension (e.g., *.txt) you use for your data files,
    // or to *.* to include all files from the directory
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.dat", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}

static string GetDestinationFilePath(string sourceFileName, string destinationPath)
{
    // This will return a file path to the file with the same name as the source
    // but located in the destination directory
    return Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileName(sourceFileName));
}

static void AppendData(string source, string destination, Func<string, bool> linePredicate)
{
    using (var inputStream = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (var inputReader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
    using (var outputStream = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
    using (var outputWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
    {
        while (inputReader.ReadLine() is string inputLine)
        {
            if (!linePredicate(inputLine))
                continue;
            outputWriter.WriteLine(inputLine);
        }
    }
}
```

In the example provided, I assumed that you have the same file name but different paths for source, destination, and completed destination file paths. If you use a different naming mechanism, please follow comments to adjust it accordingly.

Comment: While your points about the performance are of course true, they probably don't have anything to do with the exception thrown.

Comment: Sure, it's not about the original code. But with the code I provided the problem should most probably be solved